# Select the difference between two unix timestamps from 2 rows

Tags: mysql

I have a Table in MySQL with start and stop times.

i want to workout the time from the stop till the next start.

I have made a sqlfiddle with my table
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c043/1

```
ID  start_time  end_time
410 1367894268  1367898275
409 1367893164  1367894268
408 1367888257  1367893153
407 1367837969  1367888247
```

so what i would like to do is

```
end_time from row 410 - the start_time from row 409
1367898275 - 1367893164
```

and output like

```
end_time      start_time    time_duration
1367898275    1367893164    5111
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY LIKE BELOW, IT WILL HELP YOU

**SQL FIDDLE :** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c043/26

```
SELECT 
A.idtrip_data, 
A.start_time,
B.end_time, 
(B.end_time - a.start_time) AS timedifference
FROM myTable A 
INNER JOIN myTable B 
ON B.idtrip_data = (A.idtrip_data + 1)
ORDER BY A.idtrip_data ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you are asking try the following:

```
SELECT (B.start_time - A.end_time) AS time_duration
FROM MyTable A INNER JOIN MyTable B ON B.ID = (A.ID + 1)
ORDER BY A.ID ASC
```

IF `ID` is not consecutive then you can use

```
SELECT (B.start_time - A.end_time) AS time_duration
FROM MyTable A CROSS JOIN MyTable B
WHERE B.ID IN (SELECT MIN (C.ID) FROM MyTable C WHERE C.ID > A.ID)
ORDER BY A.ID ASC
```